# Probability the commuter gets to work 3 out of 4 times

Tags: probability, independence

Here's the problem:

A commuter can take one of two roads to get to work. Each road has a 50% chance of being closed independently of the other. Only one road needs to be open in order for the commuter to get to work. If both roads are closed, the commuter must go back home, there is no other way to get to work. The commuter travels to work 4 different times with enough time between each commute that we can assume the states of the roads on these four commutes are independent. What is the probability that the commuter will only be able to get to work 3 out of the 4 commutes?

I don't know where to start and I believe I'm over-thinking it.

I started by listing all possible combination of road states. Road A is open, Road B is open, and so on.

I then started to list all possible road states the commuter might encounter per commute. Commute One could be Road A is open, Road B is open, Commute One could be Road A is open, Road B is closed, and so on.

After that, I'm stuck...I don't know if I need to multiply the number of possible road states by the number of possible commutes or the number of possible open road states by the number of possible commutes then subtract the probability that a road will be closed from One and multiply the result, or if it is as simple as multiplying the likelihood of getting to work (75%) three times and then multiplying it by the likelihood of not getting to work once (25%)...I just don't know where to go next.

I can't tell if this is pairwise independence, independence of a collection of events, a conditionally independent scenario or what. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes you may be overthinking this. As you mentioned at some point that the probability of both roads being closed for a commute is $1/4$ and the probability that they can reach work in a commute is $3/4$. Now you choose one of the four commutes in which they do not reach work and in rest of them they do reach work.

Answer (score 1):

You've correctly obtained the probability of getting to work on a single commute ($3/4$).

So now you have four independent commutes, each having probability $3/4$ of being successful, and you want to know the probability of exactly $3$ successes.

- Suppose the first three are successes and the last commute fails; this happens with probability $(3/4)(3/4)(3/4)(1/4)$.
- Similarly, if it is the first commute that fails, while the last three are successful, this happens with probability $(1/4)(3/4)(3/4)(3/4)$.
- Handle the other cases similarly, and add these probabilities together.

The above computation should help you "rediscover" the probability of $3$ successes for a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) with $4$ trials and success probability $3/4$.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough. I appreciate you helping me with the clarity needed to cut through my overthinking.